# Live streaming of .flv format movie is not working if the directory is moved into other place

Tags: actionscript-3, video-streaming, streaming-flv-video

I can play the .flv movie after compilation through FlashDevelop but its not working if I move the whole directory into another PC or another Directory in the same PC. Your help will be much appreciated...Thanks

```
package 

{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;  

    import flash.media.Video;
    public class Main extends Sprite {  

        private var nc:NetConnection;
        private var ns:NetStream;
        private var vid:Video;
        private var client:Object;
        public function Main () {
            // Initialize net stream
            nc = new NetConnection();
            nc.connect (null); // Not using a media server.
            ns = new NetStream(nc);
            // Add video to stage
            vid = new Video(320,240);
            addChild (vid);
            //vid.x = ( stage.stageWidth / 2) - ( vid.width / 2 );
            //vid.y = ( stage.stageHeight / 2) - ( vid.height / 2 );
            // Changed since when deployed the
           // above set the video player nearly off the screen
           // Since I am lazy, I am just going to 0 them
           // out for now. Apparently, I have a lot more
           // to learn.
          vid.x = 0;
          vid.y = 0;  

          // Add callback method for listening on
          // NetStream meta data
          client = new Object();
          ns.client = client;
          client.onMetaData = nsMetaDataCallback;
          // Play video
          vid.attachNetStream ( ns );
          ns.play ( 'dancinggirl_1.flv' );
        }
        //MetaData
        private function nsMetaDataCallback (mdata:Object):void {
            trace (mdata.duration);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the path where your flv is located and asure the flv is located in this relative path to your swf.

```
ns.play ( 'path/to/dancinggirl_1.flv' );
```

If you embed the swf into a HTML page. The path has to be relative to the HTML, not the swf file.

Comment: I've put the whole path as you mentioned but still it's not working when I moved the whole directory into another place. Don't understand what is really going on...Thanks anyway for your advice....